# Responsive CSS Image Curtain Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, responsive-design

I am trying to produce a responsive curtain effect like the one on this page:
http://www.buildwindows.com/

The image is fixed to the top so that the content rolls over it when the user scrolls.

This seems easy if you know the height of the image, as you can just use margin-top on the content:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8NaV/

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250/0000ff/ffffff" alt="" />
</header>

<article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x1000/00ff00/ffffff" alt="" />
</article>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
```

However if you set the image to width: 100% so that it becomes responsive, the height scales up and down with the width of the browser, so the margin-top technique doesn't work. Can this effect be achieved solely with CSS, or is JavaScript required with a window resize listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a very similar effect to that (without all the complexity) by just setting the large image as a background image on the container and giving it this CSS3 property/value:

```
background-size: cover;
```

It's not exactly the same, but pretty nice. You could set a % height on the container, though that might cause the content to spill out if you aren't careful.

Here's a rough example of what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
html, body {height: 100%; margin:0; padding: 0;}
div {
height: 60%;
background-image: url(http://www.buildwindows.com/img/secret.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are also a lot of responsive JS image galleries out there that behave in a similar way, although I'm not sure I'd go that route given that you only have one image here.

EDIT: here's another experiment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
html, body {height: 100%; margin:0; padding: 0;}
.banner {
min-height: 50%;
background-image: url(http://www.buildwindows.com/img/secret.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: white;
}
h1 {margin: 0 0 40px 0; font-size: 3em;}

.banner div, .content div {width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="banner">
    <div>
        <h1>nihil concursus bonorum omnium</h1>

        <p>Quo usque tandem abutere</p>

        <p>Catilina, patientia nostra? quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet?</p>

        <p>Tum denique interficiere, cum iam nemo tam inprobus, tam perditus, tam tui similis inveniri poterit, qui id non iure factum esse fateatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div>
        <p>Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? quem ad finem sese effrenata iactabit audacia? Nihilne te nocturnum praesidium Palati, nihil urbis vigiliae, nihil timor populi, nihil concursus bonorum omnium, nihil hic munitissimus habendi senatus locus, nihil horum ora voltusque moverunt?</p>

        <p>Patere tua consilia non sentis, constrictam iam horum omnium scientia teneri coniurationem tuam non vides? Quid proxima, quid superiore nocte egeris, ubi fueris, quos convocaveris, quid consilii ceperis, quem nostrum ignorare arbitraris? </p>

        <p>O tempora, o mores! Senatus haec intellegit. consul videt; hic tamen vivit. Vivit? immo vero etiam in senatum venit, fit publici consilii particeps, notat et designat oculis ad caedem unum quemque nostrum. Nos autem fortes viri satis facere rei publicae videmur, si istius furorem ac tela vitemus. Ad mortem te, Catilina, duci iussu consulis iam pridem oportebat, in te conferri pestem, quam tu in nos omnes iam diu machinaris.</p> 

        <p>An vero vir amplissumus, P. Scipio, pontifex maximus, Ti. Gracchum mediocriter labefactantem statum rei publicae privatus interfecit; Catilinam orbem terrae caede atque incendiis vastare cupientem nos consules perferemus? Nam illa nimis antiqua praetereo, quod C. Servilius Ahala Sp. Maelium novis rebus studentem manu sua occidit.</p>

        <p>Fuit, fuit ista quondam in hac re publica virtus, ut viri fortes acrioribus suppliciis civem perniciosum quam acerbissimum hostem coercerent.</p> 

        <p>Habemus senatus consultum in te, Catilina, vehemens et grave, non deest rei publicae consilium neque auctoritas huius ordinis; nos, nos, dico aperte, consules desumus.</p> 

        <p>Decrevit quondam senatus, ut L. Opimius consul videret, ne quid res publica detrimenti caperet; nox nulla intercessit; interfectus est propter quasdam seditionum suspiciones C. Gracchus, clarissimo patre, avo, maioribus, occisus est cum liberis M. Fulvius consularis.</p> 

        <p>Simili senatus consulto C. Mario et L. Valerio consulibus est permissa res publica; num unum diem postea L. Saturninum tribunum pl. et C. Servilium praetorem mors ac rei publicae poena remorata est? At vero nos vicesimum iam diem patimur hebescere aciem horum auctoritatis.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: Here's another version that has more of the curtain effect being mentioned (also linked in the notes below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

body {
    margin:0; padding: 0;
    background-image: url(http://www.buildwindows.com/img/secret.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: #27485b;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    h1 {margin: 0 0 40px 0; font-size: 3em;}

    .head div, .content div {width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;}

    .content {background: white;}

    .head {min-height: 500px; color: white;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">
            <div>
            <h1>nihil concursus bonorum omnium</h1>

            <p>Quo usque tandem abutere</p>

            <p>Catilina, patientia nostra? quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet?</p>

            <p>Catilina, patientia nostra? quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet?</p>

            <p>Catilina, patientia nostra? quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet?</p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div>
            <p>Tum denique interficiere, cum iam nemo tam inprobus, tam perditus, tam tui similis inveniri poterit, qui id non iure factum esse fateatur.</p>
            <p>Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? quem ad finem sese effrenata iactabit audacia? Nihilne te nocturnum praesidium Palati, nihil urbis vigiliae, nihil timor populi, nihil concursus bonorum omnium, nihil hic munitissimus habendi senatus locus, nihil horum ora voltusque moverunt?</p>

            <p>Patere tua consilia non sentis, constrictam iam horum omnium scientia teneri coniurationem tuam non vides? Quid proxima, quid superiore nocte egeris, ubi fueris, quos convocaveris, quid consilii ceperis, quem nostrum ignorare arbitraris? </p>

            <p>O tempora, o mores! Senatus haec intellegit. consul videt; hic tamen vivit. Vivit? immo vero etiam in senatum venit, fit publici consilii particeps, notat et designat oculis ad caedem unum quemque nostrum. Nos autem fortes viri satis facere rei publicae videmur, si istius furorem ac tela vitemus. Ad mortem te, Catilina, duci iussu consulis iam pridem oportebat, in te conferri pestem, quam tu in nos omnes iam diu machinaris.</p> 

            <p>An vero vir amplissumus, P. Scipio, pontifex maximus, Ti. Gracchum mediocriter labefactantem statum rei publicae privatus interfecit; Catilinam orbem terrae caede atque incendiis vastare cupientem nos consules perferemus? Nam illa nimis antiqua praetereo, quod C. Servilius Ahala Sp. Maelium novis rebus studentem manu sua occidit.</p>

            <p>Fuit, fuit ista quondam in hac re publica virtus, ut viri fortes acrioribus suppliciis civem perniciosum quam acerbissimum hostem coercerent.</p> 

            <p>Habemus senatus consultum in te, Catilina, vehemens et grave, non deest rei publicae consilium neque auctoritas huius ordinis; nos, nos, dico aperte, consules desumus.</p> 

            <p>Decrevit quondam senatus, ut L. Opimius consul videret, ne quid res publica detrimenti caperet; nox nulla intercessit; interfectus est propter quasdam seditionum suspiciones C. Gracchus, clarissimo patre, avo, maioribus, occisus est cum liberis M. Fulvius consularis.</p> 

            <p>Simili senatus consulto C. Mario et L. Valerio consulibus est permissa res publica; num unum diem postea L. Saturninum tribunum pl. et C. Servilium praetorem mors ac rei publicae poena remorata est? At vero nos vicesimum iam diem patimur hebescere aciem horum auctoritatis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how do you know how far down the content should start based on the current height of the image

Comment: We might need a bit more information about what you are trying to do. I've added a simple example above, which might need some work. Really, if you use a background image you don't need to set height on the container as the content will give it height. Any content that you want below the image will just sit naturally below the image container, in the normal flow of the document.

Comment: i'm trying to have an image, or possibly an image slider fill up the entire width of the page while the height adjusts to maintain the original aspect ratio. content that sits below the slider will then roll over it like a curtain when the user scrolls

Comment: I don't really understand your use of the word curtain here. Are you describing something in the Microsoft page? Anyhow, I've added a fuller example above, though it may not suit.

Comment: sorry, i've seen it called curtain elsewhere but probably isn't an official name. see how in my original fiddle the bottom image scrolls over the top one, rather than the top image simply scrolling up along with the bottom one? it's like a curtain being lifted on a real stage, revealing the stage behind it

Comment: O, now I see. Sorry for not getting it. (I didn't actually think to scroll the MS site. OK, here's another try: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxoBh

Comment: thanks, could you please edit your answer to include the solution in the codepen?

Comment: Yep, done. :-) I modified the background color on the body element to better match the image. (It's needed in case the browser window gets very narrow.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set the height:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; /*or whatever*/
}
```

Comment: i want the image to retain its dimensions